# Perl HTML Encoding Named Entities

Tags: perl, character-encoding, entities

I would like to encode 'special chars' to their named entity.

My code:

```
use HTML::Entities;
print encode_entities('“');
```

Desired output:

```
&ldquo;
```

And not:

```
&#147;
```

Does anyone have an idea? Greetings

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using? Where is the input string from? Are you using `encode_entities`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl doesn't know the encoding of your source file. If you include any special characters, you should always save it with `UTF-8`-encoding and put

```
use utf8;
```

at the top of your code. This will make sure your string literals contain codepoints, not just bytes.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work.

If i add your line on top of the code, it will give me this error: "Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal)".

Also, if I put the character in a text file, and open it and then encode it, I get the same error (when using "open qw/:std :utf8/;"). Because normal open would still output &#147 ;.

Comment: Huh? Are you sure you saved the file as UTF-8 first? If so, can you provide the output of `od -t x1c your-file` (assuming you're on *nix), or any other hexdump?

Comment: Forgot to set encoding utf8. Never done it before, but now it works great thank you.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work when opening a file. It works when I have the character in the source code now, but when opening a file i still get that Malformed error. Is "use open qw/:std :utf8/;" not enough?

Comment: @P.Henderson The `:std` argument applies the `:utf8` to STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, but not to other file handles. An `open ':utf8'` without the `:std` restriction should work better, as would a manually specified layer on the FH: `open my $fh, "<:utf8", $filename`.

Answer (score 4):

- If you don't use `use utf8;`, the file is expected to be encoded using iso-8859-1 (or subset US-ASCII).

  «“» is not found in iso-8859-1's charset.
- If you use `use utf8;`, the file is expected to be encoded using UTF-8.

  «“» is found in UTF-8's charset, Unicode.

You indicated your file isn't saved as UTF-8, so as far as Perl is concerned, your source file cannot possibly contain «“».

Odds are that you encoded your file using [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252), an extension of iso-8859-1 that adds «“». That's not a valid choice.

Options:

- [Best option] Save the file as UTF-8 and use the following:

  ```
  use utf8;
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities('“');
  ```
- Save the file as cp1252, but only use US-ASCII characters.

  ```
  use charnames ':full';
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities("\N{LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}");
  ```

  or

  ```
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities("\N{U+201C}");
  ```

  or

  ```
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities("\x{201C}");
  ```
- [Unrecommended] Save the file as cp1252 and decode literals explicitly

  ```
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities(decode('cp1252', '“'));
  ```

  Perl sees:

  ```
  use HTML::Entities;
  print encode_entities(decode('cp1252', "\x93"));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and applied all of the above hints. It worked from within my perl script (CGI), e.g. `&auml; = encode_entities("ä")` produced the correct result. Yet applying `encode_entities(param("test"))` would encode the single bytes.

I found this advice: http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/12/character-encoding-in-perl-decodeutf8.html

Putting it together this is my solution which finally works:

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use utf8;
use HTML::Entities;
use Encode;
print encode_entities(decode_utf8(param("test")));
```

It is not clear to me why that was required, but it works. HTH

Comment: +1 This worked for me. Hopefully this doesn't mean we need to replace encode_entities( ... ) with encode_entities(decode_utf8( ... )) across our entire project. We are continuing to investigate.